# Как подать массив данных Y из обучающей выборки на вход классифирующей модели?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Есть модель, нужно подать данные (массив входных и выходных значений) так, чтобы модель классифицировала данные, и указать нужную функцию активации на последнем слое и функцию потерь. То же самое сделать для Унитарно кодированного вектора на выходном массиве данных.

(`[0,0,1]` первое значение, `[0,1,0]` второе значение, `[1,0,0]` третье значение)

Во всех статьях и книгах данные загружаются уже готовые из репозиториев, но если создавать собственные данные то возникает проблема.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from sklearn import preprocessing
model=Sequential()
X = np.array([[40, 80, 30, 60], [100, 40, 20, 80], [90, 190, 10, 15]])
Y = np.array([[0], [1], [2]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adamax', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=3,epochs=1000,
          verbose=1)
a=np.array([40, 80, 30, 60]);
   reshy =a.reshape((1,- 1))
print("test")
print(reshy)
prediction = model.predict(reshy)
print('prediction')
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы пытаетесь сделать называется `Multilabel Classification`. В этом случае массив `Y` необходимо преобразовать к `One-Hot-Encoded` виду:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

Y = to_categorical(Y)
```

чтобы получилось:

```
In [76]: Y
Out[76]:
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Кроме этого надо будет изменить архитектуру НС:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adamax', metrics=['acc'])
```

**NOTE:** обратите внимание на `loss`-function: `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` и функцию активации на последнем слое: `activation='softmax'`.

Вывод:

```
...
Epoch 47/50
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 0us/step - loss: 0.3294 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 48/50
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 0us/step - loss: 0.3226 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 49/50
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3158 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 50/50
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 0us/step - loss: 0.3091 - acc: 1.0000
test
[[40 80 30 60]]
prediction
[[0.5021875  0.297052   0.20076045]]
```

Весь код:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, BatchNormalization
from sklearn import preprocessing
model=Sequential()
X = np.array([[40, 80, 30, 60], [100, 40, 20, 80], [90, 190, 10, 15]])
Y = np.array([[0], [1], [2]])

Y = to_categorical(Y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adamax', metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=3,epochs=100,
          verbose=1)
a=np.array([40, 80, 30, 60]);
reshy =a.reshape((1,- 1))
print("test")
print(reshy)
prediction = model.predict(reshy)
print('prediction')
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Как представить данные для функции потерь binary_crossentropy, вы не могли бы порекомендовать литературу где описываются способ подачи данных и функции потерь которые нужно использовать